# How do I keep my JMS message listener listening indefinitely

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, listener

My code has two different JMS queues on different places. It takes a message from one queue, does some processing, builds a new message, and puts it on another queue to be picked up by a different process. Although it works what I want is for the listener to listen continuously so that whenever a new message is put on the first queue it is picked up.
Main method of my listener:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
    parseArgs(args);
    AMessageListener aMessageListener = new AMessageListener();
    try {
        aMessageListener.startListener();
        Thread.sleep(100000);
        aMessageListener.destroy();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    aMessageListener.destroy();
}
```

And the code I use to start the listener:

```java
public void startListener() throws JMSException{
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ACTIVE_MQ_FACTORY_URL);
    conn = connectionFactory.createConnection(jmsBrokerUser, jmsBrokerPass);
    conn.start();

    Session session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Queue queue = session.createQueue("some.in.queue");
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
    consumer.setMessageListener(this);
}
```

I have been looking online to try to find any best practices but there's little to find. An obvious way to get what I want is to put `while(true)` where I have the `Thread.sleep(100000)`. I don't really feel like that's a clean way of doing it.

Are there any different/better ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is apparently a simple command-line application you could use `System.in.read()` so that the program exits when the user presses the enter key. Or if you wanted to prevent accidental closures you could make it so the user had to type a specific keyword like "exit" or "quit," etc.

Aside from that I don't see any problem with using `while(true)` although I'd use it in conjunction with `Thread.sleep()`, e.g.:

```java
while(true) {
   Thread.sleep(100000);
}
```

Also, I would recommend you put `aMessageListener.destroy();` in a `finally` block instead of having it your code twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most terse way to lock up forever

```
Thread.currentThread().join(); // Sleep forever, waiting for ourselves to finish
```

That said you should really have an application that either restarts failed connections or dies along with the connection so something higher up can restart your JVM. To that end, I would turn main into a polling loop that checks `Session` or `Connection` every second.